# Vue Module federation child components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, webpack-module-federation

I am struggling with webpack module federation plugin and child components.

I forked from [vue3-demo](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/vue3-demo) which is working as expected. (simple example)

But when I create more complex component which contains another component it is not rendered.
In my case it is TextField which contains TextInput.

I created minimal version where I want to show you my issue with module federation webpack plugin.

I commited my example [in here](https://github.com/michalpaukert/module-federation)

Could you please help me anyone, why it is not working?
Is it a bug?
I tried same with react and it works.

Results:
Component TextField is not rendered.
[Result image](https://dev-to-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/i/mdm8smkyihq2ueq6h75y.PNG)

Comment: The link to your example seems to be broken. Have you already solved the problem?